# How to set event triggers per job rather than per workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

Let's take as an example this workflow with two jobs - *build* and *comment*:

```
name: TestWorkflow

on:  
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build code
        run: |
          whoami
          ./build
  comment:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    needs: build
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          github-token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
          script: |
            github.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: 'Test comment'
            })
```

This workflow would be triggered on both pushes and open pull requests to the *master* branch. However, while build always succeeds, the *comment* job will fail in the *push* scenario as there's no Pull Request to comment on.

Would it be possible to specify the triggers per job instead of per workflow? Something like:

```
name: TestWorkflow2

jobs:
  build:
    on:  
      push:
        branches: [ master ]
      pull_request:
        branches: [ master ]
    ...
  comment:
    on:  
      pull_request:
        branches: [ master ]
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `if` conditional [(reference)](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#) to prevent a job or a step from running unless a condition is met.

For example, here, you could add `if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}` to the `comment job` to execute it only if the event that triggered the workflow is a `pull_request`.

```
  comment:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    needs: build
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
    steps:
       [...]
```